# Backtesting a trading strategy of buy and sell using backtesting package

Tags: python

I tried to backtest a strategy of buying and selling a stock using package backtesting but i obtain the same result for all (i,j).
The code is bellow

```
from backtesting import Backtest, Strategy
from fastquant import get_stock_data
vix=get_stock_data("^VIX","2007-06-01","2010-01-01")
vix=vix.reset_index()
vix=vix.rename(columns={'dt':'','open':'Open','high':'High','low':'Low','close':'Close','volume':'Volume'})
vix=vix.set_index('')
class vixstrategy(Strategy):
    def init(self):
        price = self.data.Close
    def next(self):
        self.buy_int=i
        self.sell_int=j
        self.buy()
        self.sell()
table=[]
for i in range(10,30,5):
    for j in range(30,50,5):
        bt = Backtest(vix, vixstrategy,exclusive_orders=True)
        resultat = bt.run()
        print(resultat) 
        table.append(resultat[["Equity Final [$]","Return [%]","Sharpe Ratio","Max. Drawdown [%]","# Trades","Avg. Trade Duration","Duration","Max. Trade Duration"]])
        bt.plot()
df = pandas.DataFrame(table)
print(df)
```

Could you give me some suggestions

Comment: Hm. You could try printing out i and j in the next-method. I was very surprised to see that I have to admit. 
Is the `resultat` that you print out with every iteration then also always the same?

Comment: thanks Christian for your reply. Yes i get the same "resultat" in every iteration

Comment: There is no way the next method gets the right i and j variables from the nested loop, your scopes are wrong.
You can pass them with bt.run(i=i, j=j), and retrieve them as named parameter on the __init__ method.
Like: https://github.com/kernc/backtesting.py/issues/378

Comment: Thanks @Ludwing but i didn't understand your response. Could you explain it more please

Comment: @Soadboul the point is, t hat you are using i and j there in this next-method, but those variables are defined somewhere completely else (the for loops). That's why I also asked, whether you put a printout in the next-method for whether they actually change there. 
I don't know this library so that might be an issue, even though I tried to recreate a small example with your approach and there it actually did work.

Comment: @Christian. No i didn't print i and j in my output. Could you write your example here please

Comment: I mean, just make a `print(j)` and `print(i)` inside the `next(self)` method. At some point this should be called and then it's important, which value is actually being set to `buy_int` and `sell_int`.

`
def next(self):
        self.buy_int=i
        self.sell_int=j
        print(i)
        print(j)
        print(self.buy_int)
        print(self.sell_int)
        self.buy()
        self.sell()
`

(Sorry, I don't know how to nicely format that in the comments.)